# Stored Proc with multiple selects - run each select in async

Tags: sql-server, blazor

I have a Blazor Server app that calls a stored proc - which contains multiple SELECT statements - I use Dapper to convert my SP response into an object(s).  The call to the SP is async within .Net - which works well

However I was thinking - can I make the calls within my SP async.  As none of the SELECTS are dependent on each other.  Is there a way to tell SQL Server to do all 3 at the same time .  Is there any real time saving in using such approach?

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetVariousSelects]
SELECT * FROM Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2
SELECT * FROM Table3
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Move each into its own procedure and call async using Dapper?

Comment: *"Is there a way to tell SQL Server to do all 3 at the same time"* No. SQL is run sequentially, with each statement run after the prior statement in the batch completes. You can't tell it to run 3 statements in the same batch at the same time; you would need to make 3 separate calls from your application, 1 for each statement you need.

Comment: Ahh okay - I may look into doing multiple async calls from Dapper

Thanks again both for all your great advice!

Comment: Given the fact that most databases are IO constrained, then unless you store all three tables on different disks you probably won't see any benefit anyway